# How to improve this regex that I wrote?

Tags: java, regex

I wrote this regex.

```
(?i)(#?covid\s|#?covid\W|#?covid\d+)
```

But it doesn't seem to match uppercase word (COVID). How can I improve it?

Note: One of the requirements is to match covid4me&u. So when there is a number after the word covid is a valid expression.

Comment: it will not match the string `"COVID"` (or `"covid"`) ! It **must** have a trailing white space (`\s`) or a non-word character (`\W`) or at least one digit (`\d+`)

Comment: It should match it : https://regex101.com/r/HegPg1/1; You could improve your regex by factorizing it : `(?i)#?covid(\s|\W|\d+)`

Comment: Ah, note that your regex forces matching an additional character after COVID (either a space, a non-word character or some numbers), so COVID at the end of a line (or alone on its own) won't be matched

Comment: For some reasons, regex shows the correct result. But my java code doesn't take into account COVID.                          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)#?covid(\\s|\\W|\\d+)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tweet.getText());
            boolean matchFound = matcher.find();

Comment: Perhaps `(?i)#?\bcovid(?:\b|\d\w*)` See https://regex101.com/r/pRXJIw/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to make sure you're not matching part of a word, I would use the `\b` word-boundary instead of matching COVID followed by `\W` or `\s` :

```
(?i)#?covid\d*\b
```

This avoids problem matching covid at the end of lines that your solution was having.

To handle your updated question's needs I would use the following :

```
(?i)#?\bcovid(\b|\d+)
```

Comment: One of the requirements is to match covid4me&u. So when there is a number after the word covid is a valid expression.

Comment: @Damien this SHOULD have been included in question - now you are changing the question and invalidating all effort spent trying to help you  :-/

Comment: @Aaron One of the requirements is to match covid4me&u. So when there is a number after the word covid is a valid expression.

Comment: @DamienAsseya does (?i)#?covid(\b|\d*) work for you ?

Comment: @Aaron It does not. (?i)#?covid(\b|\d*) makes #covide and covide a valid expression. They should not be. But #covid4e, covid19u, covid2022i should be considered valid expressions.

Comment: @user16320675 I added the requirement to my post.

Comment: @DamienAsseya slight mistake, try `(?i)#?covid(\b|\d+)` instead

Comment: @Aaron It didn't work.

Comment: @DamienAsseya it matches the covid from "covid4u&me" : https://regex101.com/r/4fNxk3/1 ; isn't that what you wanted ?

Comment: @DamienAsseya I've successfully tested your java code, if it still doesn't work for you can you provide a way to reproduce ? You can fork that ideone : https://ideone.com/p7wii2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246928/discussion-between-damien-asseya-and-aaron).

Comment: @Aaron newcovid also matches, but it shouldn't. A valid expression must start with #covid or covid

Comment: `(?i)#?\bcovid(\b|\d+)` ; `\b` is the word-boundary metacharacter, apply it where you want to match between a letter, number or underscore and something that is neither

Comment: @Aaron `(?i)#?\bcovid(\b|\d+)` worked. Thanks!